# JAVA disable other form select

Tags: java, forms, select

How to disable selecting of main/other forms under opened form. I want that then selecting other form, opened form starts blinking and not allows to select form under it. How I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing really, didn't find anything like that, only setEnabled(false), but this  is not that what I need.

Comment: can you give more specific on your issue like framework,technology,your code ?

Comment: I can't, this not and issue, I just didn't know how to do that, now I have main form which opens other forms (and other forms open more forms too), so I want that froms which is under the top form, can't be selected, and on try the top form starts blinking like windows forms then you need to close top form to do something in that form.

Answer (score 0):

you can you methods like `setEnabled(false)` where false is the parameter passed so it is disabled.

Comment: But this can't be used from other form to set it for main form.

Comment: then you can you place two different buttons taking you to different part of form which needs to be filled and so no need to disable some part of form.